# Hibernate exception: deadlock

Tags: hibernate, db2, deadlock, websphere-portal

Exception "org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not insert" appears **sometimes** in the following code:

```
 Question questionClone;
 try {
    questionClone = (Question) question.clone();
 } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
    throw WrappedException.wrap(e);
 }
 questionClone.setCategory(question.getCategory());
 questionClone.setOriginal(false);
 logger.trace("Saving questionClone " + questionClone + " start");
 hibernateSession.save(questionClone);
 logger.trace("Saving questionClone " + questionClone + " end");
```

when questionClone is saved. Here is the clone method for Question:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Question questionClone = (Question) super.clone();

    questionClone.category = null;

    List<Alternative> alternativesClone = new ArrayList<Alternative>(getInternalAlternatives().size());
    int index = 0;
    for (Iterator<Alternative> iterator = getInternalAlternatives().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Alternative alternative = iterator.next();
        Alternative alternativeClone = (Alternative) alternative.clone();
        alternativeClone.setQuestion(questionClone);
        alternativeClone.setIndex(index);
        alternativesClone.add(alternativeClone);
        ++index;
    }
    questionClone.setInternalAlternatives(alternativesClone);

    return questionClone;
}
```

And clone method for Alternative:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Alternative alternativeClone = (Alternative) super.clone();

    alternativeClone.index = 0;
    alternativeClone.question = null;

    return alternativeClone;
}
```

Hibernate mapping of question contains this:

```
<list name="internalAlternatives" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
   <cache usage="read-write"/>
   <key column="QUESTION_ID"/>
   <list-index column="INDEX"/>
   <one-to-many class="Alternative"/>
</list>
```

Exception states that it cannot insert an Alternative and caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlTransactionRollbackException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=2, DRIVER=4.14.88. As I found out it was a deadlock. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The questions are cloned when user starts the test. Can it be due to the several users starting the test at the same time? For each user the individual test session is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alternativeClone.setQuestion(questionClone);
```

and

```
questionClone.setInternalAlternatives(alternativesClone);
```

Seems to be the `dealock` occurs becuase of these lines. You are adding list on `internalAlternatives` inside your `question`, and then also setting `question` inside `alternative`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When I was testing it, it worked fine without throwing an exception. However that application is already in use and the exception appeared there. Can it be the reason that several people start the test at the same time and the set of alternatives get locked?